# Need count a value while on change function for checkbox check

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Hi all am trying add priority number using on change function for check box. While select the checkbox if it was checked need add it as 1.am having list of checkbox within a div I check any one checkbox need to mark it as one if select next means need to mark it as two by the way everything. Now the problem the event doesn't need to trigger while already marked checkbox here my working

```
<div class="it">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="span"/> 1
        </label>
    <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="span"/> 2
        </label>
    <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="span"/> 3
        </label>
    <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="span"/> 4
        </label>
    <br>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

my jquery

```
$(function () {
    var count = 0;
    $('.span').on('change', function() {
        if(this.checked) {
            count ++;
            $('span').text(count);
        }

    })

})
```

please help the count will added only once for a checkbox [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tL8axe9k/2/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to count checked boxes I suggest this

```js
$(function () {
    $('.span').on('click', function() {
      $('span').text($(".span:checked").length);
    }).triggerHandler("click"); // handle reload and initial counter
});
```

```css
div label {
    display:block;
}
div label:after{
    clear:right;
    content:" ";
}
.badge {
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="it">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="span"/> 1
        </label>
    <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="span"/> 2
        </label>
    <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="span"/> 3
        </label>
    <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="span"/> 4
        </label>
    <br>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi can you please help this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27294318/sort-checkbox-length-list-in-sequtial-order-using-jquery

Answer (score 2):

You can count the `:checked` checkboxes. To display the number of checked checkboxes you can also use an attribute, see snippet.

```js
$('.it [type=checkbox]')
  .on('click', function() {
      $('[data-count]').attr('data-count',$('.it [type=checkbox]:checked').length);
   }
  );
```

```css
label {
    display: block;
}

div label:after{
    clear: right;
    content: " ";
}

[data-count]:after {
    content: attr(data-count)' checked';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="it">
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="span"/> 1</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="span"/> 2</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="span"/> 3</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="span"/> 4</label>
    <span data-count=0></span>
</div>
```

You don't need [**JQuery per se**](http://jsfiddle.net/vvzr9zt7/), by the way.

Comment: Interesting +1 - but why not .data("count") ?

Comment: Because `$.data(...)` doesn't work whith the initial attribute value already defined within the html.

Comment: *And* because `$.data` doesn't actually create/modifies a `data-* attribute`  for the element, so the css won't work either. You can however use `.dataset` to set/modify the attribute, see http://jsfiddle.net/ow1jqn2h/

Comment: it should work http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/ : `$('#counter').data('count',$('.it [type=checkbox]:checked').length);` or are you saying the CSS will not like that method?

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm saying. *jQuery cleverly attempts to convert the data to a suitable type (booleans, numbers, objects, arrays or null) and **avoids touching the DOM*** (source: http://www.sitepoint.com/use-html5-data-attributes/)

Comment: hi could you please help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27294318/sort-checkbox-length-list-in-sequtial-order-using-jquery

Answer (score 1):

Try this ...

```
if(this.checked) {
    count ++;
} else {
    count--;
}
$('span').text(count);
```

This accounts for addition when checking and subtraction when unchecking a checkbox.

See **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rfornal/tL8axe9k/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(function () {
  var count = 0;
  $('.span').on('change', function() {        
     count =  $('.span:checked').length;        
      $('span').text(count);       
    });
 });
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tL8axe9k/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function () {
    $('.span').on('change', function() {
        $('span').text ( $( ".span:checked" ).length );
    });
});
```