# Sort checkbox length list in sequtial order using jquery

Tags: jquery, sorting, checkbox

Hi all am trying to do sort a number by `checkbox: checked`  in a sequential order.

```
<div class="box sortable">
            <label class="label_select"><input type="checkbox" class="rule" />Rule list <span class="badges"></span></label>
            <label class="label_select"><input type="checkbox" class="rule" />Rule list <span class="badges"></span></label>
            <label class="label_select"><input type="checkbox" class="rule" />Rule list <span class="badges"></span></label>
            <label class="label_select"><input type="checkbox" class="rule" />Rule list <span class="badges"></span></label>
            <label class="label_select"><input type="checkbox" class="rule" />Rule list <span class="badges"></span></label>
            <label class="label_select"><input type="checkbox" class="rule" />Rule list <span class="badges"></span></label>
       </div>
```

I already get a value by counting the checked list using 'checked' condition in Jquery

```
$('.rule').on('change', function() {
        if(this.checked) {
            count ++;
            $(this).next('.badges').show().text(count);
        }
})
```

Please look out the [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vikranth/62Ly34yt/4/)
Now the matter is I want to negotiate the value if I uncheck the checked list.
for uncheck

```
if(!this.checked) {
            count --;
            $(this).next('.badges').hide().text(count);
            console.log("count:" +count);
            var reduce= parseInt($(this).parent().closest('.box').find('[type=checkbox]:checked').next('.badges').text());
            reduce = reduce - 1;
            if(!reduce==0) {
                $(this).parent().closest('.box').find('[type=checkbox]:checked').next('.badges').show().empty().text(reduce);
            }
        }
```

For example  there are four list. I selected 1, 3 and 5 and the value added in badge as 1st - 1, 3rd - 2 and 5th - 3.

if I Unchecked the 3 means the badge value of  other list get into sequential order 1 as 1 and 5th as 2.

And I selected 1,3 and 5 and the value added in badge as 1st - 1, 3rd - 2 and 5th - 3.If I selected 2nd list means the values of list has to change 1st as 1 2nd as 2 and by the way others

I stuck here while uncheck am completely out of mind give some ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean, but i think it's something like ...

```
$(function () {
    $('.badges').hide();
    $('.rule').on('click', function() {
        $('.badges').hide();
        var selected = $('.box [type=checkbox]:checked');
        selected.each(function(i, cb) {
            $(cb).next('.badges').text(i+1).show();
        });
    })
});
```

Here's a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/gnkd9e5p/) using that code. Let me know if understood correctly?

Comment: And this function is not working while droppable event in sorting jquery UI http://jsfiddle.net/oa5yx1j7/1/

Comment: @Joseph: making the drop asynchronous helps. `drop: function(ev, ui){ setTimeout(orderRule,10); }`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to iterate through all checkboxes and reassign the batch value, when one is changed. This can be done with the [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) method for example. Check the snippet below:

```js
$(function () {
 $('.badges').hide();
 
 $('.rule').on('change', function() {
        var count = 0;
        $.each($('.rule'), function(i, val) {
            if(this.checked) {
                count ++;
                $(this).next('.badges').show().text(count);  
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).next('.badges').hide();
            }
        });
 });
});
```

```css
 .box {
   padding:10px;
   border:1px solid #ccc;
   width:250px;
  }
  .box .label_select {
   display:block;
   height:25px;
   line-height:25px;
   cursor:pointer;
   margin-bottom:2px;
   font-size:13px;
  }
  .box .label_select:after {
   clear:both;
   content: " ";
   display:block;
  }
  .badges {
   float:right;
   display:inline-block;
   background-color:#666;
   border-radius:50%;
   padding: 0px 5px;
   min-width:10px;
   text-align:center;
   position:relative;
   top:-2px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box sortable">
   <label class="label_select"><input type="checkbox" class="rule" />Rule list <span class="badges"></span></label>
   <label class="label_select"><input type="checkbox" class="rule" />Rule list <span class="badges"></span></label>
   <label class="label_select"><input type="checkbox" class="rule" />Rule list <span class="badges"></span></label>
   <label class="label_select"><input type="checkbox" class="rule" />Rule list <span class="badges"></span></label>
   <label class="label_select"><input type="checkbox" class="rule" />Rule list <span class="badges"></span></label>
   <label class="label_select"><input type="checkbox" class="rule" />Rule list <span class="badges"></span></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So when you uncheck, I save the current value of the unchecked badge and hide it.
I then get all visible badges and if they are >1 and > the unchecked value, I subtract 1 from each

```js
$(function () {
    $('.badges').hide();
    var count = 0;
    $('.rule').on('change', function () {
        var $currentBadge = $(this).next('.badges');
        if (this.checked) {
            count++;
            $currentBadge.show().text(count);
        } else if (!this.checked) {
            count--;
            var thisVal = parseInt($currentBadge.text(),10);
            $currentBadge.hide().text("");

            $(".badges:visible").each(function () {
                var val = parseInt($(this).text(),10);
                if (val != 1 && val > thisVal) $(this).text(val- 1);
            });
            var reduce = parseInt($(this).parent().closest('.box').find('[type=checkbox]:checked').next('.badges').text());

        }
    })
})
```

```css
.box {
     padding:10px;
     border:1px solid #ccc;
     width:250px;
 }
 .box .label_select {
     display:block;
     height:25px;
     line-height:25px;
     cursor:pointer;
     margin-bottom:2px;
     font-size:13px;
 }
 .box .label_select:after {
     clear:both;
     content:" ";
     display:block;
 }
 .badges {
     float:right;
     display:inline-block;
     background-color:#ccc;
     border-radius:50%;
     padding: 0px 5px;
     min-width:10px;
     text-align:center;
     position:relative;
     top:-2px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box sortable">
   <label class="label_select"><input type="checkbox" class="rule" />Rule list <span class="badges"></span></label>
   <label class="label_select"><input type="checkbox" class="rule" />Rule list <span class="badges"></span></label>
   <label class="label_select"><input type="checkbox" class="rule" />Rule list <span class="badges"></span></label>
   <label class="label_select"><input type="checkbox" class="rule" />Rule list <span class="badges"></span></label>
   <label class="label_select"><input type="checkbox" class="rule" />Rule list <span class="badges"></span></label>
   <label class="label_select"><input type="checkbox" class="rule" />Rule list <span class="badges"></span></label>
    </div>
```